# Accessing Elasticsearch from python when it's configured with Google Auth

Tags: python, elasticsearch, google-authentication

I'm trying to access a remote Elasticsearch cluster from a python script.  The cluster is configured with SAML using Google Auth, and I can successfully access it through my web browser with my Google id and password. I've looked at the doc for both the requests package and the Elasticsearch package and it's not clear to me that either support this type of authentication.  I've tried just passing my username and password using requests but access is denied. I've also looked at the Elasticsearch SAML documentation but am not clear whether I need to be using those API calls.  Would appreciate any tips from someone who's successfully done this.

Comment: Hi Ruth, usually the SAML authentication scheme is for use in web applications (like Kibana), and typically don't get used via the CLI or in scripts. Is it possible that your ES cluster has been configured to use multiple authentication "realms", allowing for a different authentication mechanism? Usually the `native` realm is used for accounts like this that get used in scripts.

Comment: Thanks, Ian.  I am not sure how it's configured in terms of realms but I can ask.  I do know they just recently enabled it for OAUTH2 and I will now be getting an API access token, so perhaps that will make it more clear.